# Resource recommendations on Renormalization Group Flow

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, renormalization

I've read two notes on RG flow:

1. [RENORMALIZATION GROUP: AN INTRODUCTION, J. ZINN-JUSTIN](http://www-math.unice.fr/~patras/CargeseConference/ACQFT09_JZinnJustin.pdf)
2. [The Renormalization Group, David Skinner](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/dbs26/AQFT/Wilsonchap.pdf)

I've also read RG flow on Peskin's. I think have to say I still don't have a clear image of the meaning of RG flow since the notes I've read so far discuss the topic with a particular example mostly with real scalar field. In addition, I read in a paper that there are several different types of RG flow and it makes me even more confused.

> Can you suggest me a good reference on RG flow based on more mathematical language? I need to grasp a precise general overview!

Comment: I answered your question at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/372306/ namely I explained RG in "more mathematical language"