Why do we rescale momenta after integrating out high momenta in Wilsonian renormalization?
In Section 12.1 of Peskin & Schroeder they motivate Wilson's approach to renormalization by asking how a quantum field theory changes after changing the momentum scale. To answer this they start with a momentum scale $\Lambda$ and integrate out a single momentum shell in the path integral to get to a momentum scale $\Lambda'=b\lambda$ with $b<1$. The result is a new Lagrangian and hence a new action. I understand this part so far.
What confuses me is they proceed by rescaling the momenta:
$$k' = \frac{k}{b}, \quad x' = bx, \tag{12.19}$$
where $b$ is chosen so that the cutoff $\Lambda'$ is restored back to $\Lambda$. They claim this is done so that we can compare the modified path integral (with the momentum shell integrated out) to the original one. However doesn't the rescaling (12.19) undo getting rid of all momentum modes $\Lambda' < |k| < \Lambda$, since the path integral will now include momenta in this range?
They do not mention it explicitly, but I suspect even with the rescaling that somehow the information in modes $\Lambda' < |k| < \Lambda$ that was in the original path integral remains lost and is not restored, is this true? What is the physical idea and motivation behind rescaling after integrating out high momentum modes?

this was explained here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/372306/

@AbdelmalekAbdesselam Thank you, the more mathematical nature to that post was very nice. However I am still unclear on what the rescaling is doing physically. If we integrate out the high momentum modes and then rescale to go back to the original momentum scale don't we go back to where we started from?

You can find some details on this in David Tong's notes on Statistical Field Theory (the integrals are in the context of stat-phys there but the reasoning is identical).

@ThomasTappeiner Thank you. I took a look and found those notes very helpful. One point I'm still unclear about is he claims we scale the coordinates so that each path integral has the same momentum cutoff. But isn't this just a notational trick? The momentum cutoffs are still different because they are measured in different scales (one is $x$ and the other is $bx$).

@CBBAM: It's too bad you did not try to read my answer at all. You would have understood that the rescaling (which is not absolutely necessary) is doing nothing physically. It's a mathematical device like a change of coordinates. It's a bit like like using a moving frame to follow the evolution of a moving particle in classical mechanics.

@AbdelmalekAbdesselam I apologize if my reply came off as negative. I did read your answer but I had a hard time connecting it to how the RNG is presented in physics books. I think I need to read your answer a few more times to fully understand it. Thank you very much for your comments and for all the help.

OP wrote:

However doesn't the rescaling (12.19) undo getting rid of all momentum modes $\Lambda' < |k| < \Lambda$, since the path integral will now include momenta in this range?

No, the rescaling eq. (12.19) is a relabelling, so that we can make a more careful comparison of the new functional integral
$$Z~=~\int\!\left[\prod_{|k|<b\Lambda}d\hat{\phi}(k)\right]e^{-S_{\rm eff}[\phi]} \tag{12.6}$$ and the one we started with
$$Z~=~\int\!\left[\prod_{|k|<\Lambda}d\hat{\phi}(k)\right]e^{-S[\phi]}, \tag{12.3}$$ as P&S write above eq. (12.19). The effective action $S_{\rm eff}[\phi]$ (and its coupling constants) in $Z$ is typically changed under the RG flow.
It should be mentioned that not all approaches to Wilsonian RG flow include the scaling (12.19), cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer here.

This seems to answer the question, but would benefit from explicitly containing equations 12.3, 12.6, and 12.9 to be fully self-contained.

I updated the answer.

Thank you for your answer.
